# Arrows are crossing in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

The arrows from *Training Examples* and *Hypothesis Set* are crossing eachother. Is there a way to avoid this, i.e. that they change the "dock" position on *Learning Algorithm*?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [myBox/.style={rectangle,
                   draw,
                   align=center,
                   inner sep=2.5mm}]

    \node[myBox] (unknownTargetFunction) at (-4, 4) {\textsc{Unknown Target Function}\\$f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$};
    \node[myBox] (trainingExamples) at (-4, 2) {\textsc{Training Examples}\\$\mathcal{D} = (x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$};
    \node[myBox] (learningAlgorithm) at ( 0, 0) {\textsc{Learning Algorithm}\\$\mathcal{A}$};
    \node[myBox] (finalHypothesis) at ( 5, 0) {\textsc{Final Hypothesis}\\$g \approx f$};
    \node[myBox] (hypothesisSet) at (-4,-2) {\textsc{Hypothesis Set}\\$\mathcal{H}$};

    \draw [->] (unknownTargetFunction) to (trainingExamples);
    \draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right] (learningAlgorithm);
    \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] (learningAlgorithm);
    \draw [->] (learningAlgorithm) to (finalHypothesis);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code produces:
[image: LaTeX code output]

Information: The idea behind the picture originate from the book "Learning From Data" by Y. S. Abu-Mostafa et.al.

Comment: `\draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right] (learningAlgorithm.170);
    \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] (learningAlgorithm.190);`

Comment: Somewhat urelated: `...` should be `\dots` and the colon in the map should be `\colon` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have, at least, three options:

- You can use the "angle" anchors for a ņode:

  ```
  \draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right] (learningAlgorithm.170);
  \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] (learningAlgorithm.190);
  ```
- You can use the `calc` library and a partway modifier to avoid manual calculations:

  ```
  \draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right]  
    ( $ (learningAlgorithm.west)!0.5!(learningAlgorithm.north west) $ );
  \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] 
    ( $ (learningAlgorithm.west)!0.5!(learningAlgorithm.south west) $ );
  ```
- You can use the `west` anchor and a manual shift in the y direction:

  ```
  \draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right]  
    ([yshift=10pt]learningAlgorithm.west);
  \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] 
    ([yshift=-10pt]learningAlgorithm.west);
  ```

The code, showing the first two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [myBox/.style={rectangle,
                   draw,
                   align=center,
                   inner sep=2.5mm}]

    \node[myBox] (unknownTargetFunction) at (-4, 4) {\textsc{Unknown Target Function}\\$f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$};
    \node[myBox] (trainingExamples) at (-4, 2) {\textsc{Training Examples}\\$\mathcal{D} = (x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$};
    \node[myBox] (learningAlgorithm) at ( 0, 0) {\textsc{Learning Algorithm}\\$\mathcal{A}$};
    \node[myBox] (finalHypothesis) at ( 5, 0) {\textsc{Final Hypothesis}\\$g \approx f$};
    \node[myBox] (hypothesisSet) at (-4,-2) {\textsc{Hypothesis Set}\\$\mathcal{H}$};

    \draw [->] (unknownTargetFunction) to (trainingExamples);
    \draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right] (learningAlgorithm.170);
    \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] (learningAlgorithm.190);
    \draw [->] (learningAlgorithm) to (finalHypothesis);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [myBox/.style={rectangle,
                   draw,
                   align=center,
                   inner sep=2.5mm}]

    \node[myBox] (unknownTargetFunction) at (-4, 4) {\textsc{Unknown Target Function}\\$f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$};
    \node[myBox] (trainingExamples) at (-4, 2) {\textsc{Training Examples}\\$\mathcal{D} = (x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$};
    \node[myBox] (learningAlgorithm) at ( 0, 0) {\textsc{Learning Algorithm}\\$\mathcal{A}$};
    \node[myBox] (finalHypothesis) at ( 5, 0) {\textsc{Final Hypothesis}\\$g \approx f$};
    \node[myBox] (hypothesisSet) at (-4,-2) {\textsc{Hypothesis Set}\\$\mathcal{H}$};

    \draw [->] (unknownTargetFunction) to (trainingExamples);
    \draw [->] (trainingExamples) to [bend right]  
    ( $ (learningAlgorithm.west)!0.5!(learningAlgorithm.north west) $ );
    \draw [->] (hypothesisSet) to [bend left] 
        ( $ (learningAlgorithm.west)!0.5!(learningAlgorithm.south west) $ );
    \draw [->] (learningAlgorithm) to (finalHypothesis);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]